# How to redirect folder to index.php of that folder using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Website structure:

website.com/folder/

website.com/folder/index.php

When I try to access website.com/folder it gives me an "No files found." error. Insted I want it to open website.com/folder/index.php like it does in root folder.

I have tried redirecting it with `RewriteRule website.com/folder/ website.com/folder/index.php` but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a redirect for this specific page with

`Redirect /folder /folder/index.php`

Or you can try this…

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

That will mean that you can access at `website/folder/index` and your server should display `index` as the root of a directory. If not try renaming to `default.php`.

Comment: The first solution puts you in an infinite loop beacuse it keeps redirecting you to the same folder. However the second solution worked perfectly. Thank you for your help

Comment: No worries, I didn't know how the rest of your server was configured or fully what you wanted to get but I'm glad one worked.